# Show an ACF gallery in a lightbox with thumbnails nav

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, gallery, lightbox

I used "Foobox" plugin to show a ACF gallery (hidden) start from a single image.
Here is the code used

```
if ( have_rows( 'lsv_prodotto' ) ) {
    while ( have_rows( 'lsv_prodotto' ) ) {
        the_row();
        $lsv_count = get_row_index();
        $lsv_foto_prodotto = get_sub_field( 'foto_prodotto' );
        $lsv_gallery_prodotto_images = get_sub_field( 'gallery_prodotto' );
        
        echo '<div class="lsv-box-prodotto">';
            echo '<div class="lsv-box-titolo">';
                the_sub_field( 'nome_prodotto' );
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<a class="lsv-box-img footrigger" href="lsv-hidden-gallery-' . $lsv_count . '">';
                echo '<img src="' . esc_url( $lsv_foto_prodotto['url'] ) . '" />';
            echo '</a>';
            
            // Hidden Gallery for Lighbox //
            if ($lsv_gallery_prodotto_images) {
                echo '<div id="lsv-hidden-gallery-' . $lsv_count . '" class="foobox" style="display: none;">';
                foreach($lsv_gallery_prodotto_images as $lsv_gallery_prodotto_image) { 
                    echo '<a data-caption-title="' . $lsv_gallery_prodotto_image['title'] . '" href="' . esc_url( $lsv_gallery_prodotto_image['url'] ) . '"></a>';
                } //endforeach;
                echo '</div>';
            } //endif

        echo '</div>';
    } // endwhile
} // endif
```

and this is the jQuery code

```
jQuery('.footrigger').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var hiddenAreaId = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('#'+hiddenAreaId).find('a:first').click();
});
```

Now client ask me to show thumbnails navigation inside lightbox window.
I cannot find any info about this implementation on Foobox (free).
Maybe is it possible on Foobox Pro??
Can anyone help me to understand if better to improuve this code with this plugin or needed to use another lightbox plugin... or add lightbox javascript code... a little bit confused!!
Thanks in advance!!!